# Sequel model doesn't find connection defined in a Sinatra app file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, sequel

I'm building a simple Sinatra application to show some items stored in a database. I happened to find the gem [sinatra-sequel](http://github.com/rtomayko/sinatra-sequel) that was supposed to make things easier.

To mantain the modularity I'm defining the Sinatra app in a file and the model in a different file. Unfortunately the model can't find the connection and mais my app crash. The same thing is described in this [sequel-sinatra issue](http://github.com/rtomayko/sinatra-sequel/issues/1)

I could define my model in the app class, but I prefer a more elegant solution if there is any.

Comment: Have you got a little bit of set up code you can show us to see what you've already tried?

Comment: My example almost exactly the same of the one in the github issue. I thought that was not practical to copy the same code. I found a solution but can't answer my own question now.

Comment: Ok, no bother, glad you found a solution.

Comment: iurifq, you should be able to post the solution even if you're not able to mark it as an swer.

Comment: You should always post your own code here. Even if it is "mostly" the same. It could be those minor differences that cause the problem.